# C++ ,code execution cannot proceed because libstdc++-6.dll was not found

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I tried running the .exe of the c++ source code I wrote using code blocks .but the was a system error stating ,"The code execution cannot proceed because libstdc++-6.dlll was not found". Any help will do.And a better to ide to code in c++ so I can run the .exe after completion of code.

Comment: for beginners I recommend Visual Studio Community Edition; C++ works out of the box. I personally just love VS Code, but it requires some setup to get C++ to work.

Comment: What kind of setup is required

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Comment: Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your compiler built your executable in a way that it uses a separate dll that contains the code of the standard library functions that your application uses.

There may be two solutions to your problem:

1. build a statically linked binary - this way your applications binary is independent of other dynamic objects (beside the basic OS dlls)

   - how to achieve this, you may refer your IDEs or compilers manual - keywords are "static linking" or "static linkage", ...
2. ensure that the dll is visible to the loader if you start your application.

   - Either add the directory path to the dll to your `PATH`-environment variable
   - or copy the dll next to your executable.

Keep in mind that there are some pros/cons for either static or dynamic linkage. You may inform yourself about them and make a decision for your application.